# Flatten nested loops to one list with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

I'm replacing an old parallelisation helper class of mine with the TPL classes now. My old code has proven very unreliable when errors occur in the action code and it doesn't seem to be built for what I'm doing now.

The first list of jobs was easily translated to `Parallel.ForEach`. But here comes a nested and indexed loop that I can't resolve so easily.

```
int streamIndex = 0;
foreach (var playlist in selectedPlaylists)
{
    var localPlaylist = playlist;
    foreach (var streamFile in playlist.StreamFiles)
    {
        var localStreamFile = streamFile;
        var localStreamIndex = streamIndex++;
        // Action that uses localPlaylist, localStreamFile and localStreamIndex
        ...
        // Save each job's result to its assigned place in the list
        lock (streamsList)
        {
            streamsList[localStreamIndex] = ...;
        }
    }
}
```

The local variables are for proper closure support as the foreach iteration variable was shared.

I'm thinking of something like

```
selectedPlaylists.SelectMany(p => p.StreamFiles)
```

but then I'm losing the association of where each streamFile came from, and the index which should be deterministic as it's used for ordering the results in the results list. Is there a way to keep these associations with Linq and also add that counter while enumerating the list? Maybe like this (made-up pseudocode):

```
selectedPlaylists
    .SelectMany(p => new
    {
        Playlist = p,
        StreamFile = ~~each one of p.StreamFiles~~,
        Index = ~~Counter()~~
    })
```

I could keep those old nested foreach loops and collect all jobs in a list, then use Parallel.Invoke, but that seems more complex than it needs to be. I'd like to know if there's a simple Linq feature I don't know yet.

Comment: Checkout my edit regarding Cancelationtoken and Degree of Parallelism

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you could do something like this...

```
//
Dictionary<int, object> streamsList = new Dictionary<int, object>();

// First create a composition that holds the playlist and the streamfile
selectedPlaylists.SelectMany(playList => playList.StreamFiles.Select(streamFile => new { PlayList = playList, StreamFile = streamFile }))
                 // thenfor all of theese add the respective index
                 .Select((composition, i) => new { StreamFile = composition.StreamFile, PlayList = composition.PlayList, LocalStreamIndex = i })
                 .AsParallel()

                 .WithCancellation(yourTokenGoesHere)
                 .WithDegreeOfParallelism(theDegreeGoesHere)

                 .ForAll(indexedComposition =>
                 {
                     object result =somefunc(indexedComposition.LocalStreamIndex, indexedComposition.PlayList, indexedComposition.StreamFile);;
                     lock(streamsList) // dont call the function insde the lock or the as parallel is useless.
                         streamsList[indexedComposition.LocalStreamIndex] = result;

                 });
```

Comment: This looks good. Indexing works correct. I cannot use the `ForAll` method because it doesn't let me set the ParallelOptions (MaxDegreeOfParallelism and CancellationToken), but the Linq query is also good for `Parallel.ForEach`. Good to know it exists though!

Comment: You can...
.AsParallel().WithCancellation(yourTokenGoesHere).WithDegreeOfParallelism(50).ForAll()

Answer (score 1):

To flatten the `StreamFiles` and keep association with `PlayList` and index them you canuse this query:

```
int index = 0;
var query = selectedPlaylists
              .SelectMany(p => p.StreamFiles
                               .Select(s =>
                                          new {
                                                PlayList = p,
                                                Index = index++,
                                                StreamFile = s
                                              }));
```

Comment: I believe your index is only from the "first" level of iteration, and doesnt take the second "level" into account.
I mean its the same for every streamfile of the same playlist.

Comment: Good that you pointed this out. The indexing worked in my first test, but as I was looking for a specific set of lists, the index is actually wrong.

Comment: @LonelyPixel Yes, that's the issue. But it is easy to solve. See update.